# Mongo Db - Updating Date with a where and Between Date conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
Update Table Table_Name
Set ObservationTime = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
Where ObservationTime Between 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' and 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
```

Please help me to replicate the same in Mongo Db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below

```
db.col.updateMany(
    {ObservationTime : {$gte: "minTime"}, ObservationTime : {$lt : "maxTime"}},
    {$set : {ObservationTime : "newTime"}}
)
```

here

```
minTime - is your start time
maxTime - is your end time
newTime - time to be updated
```